# VS Code debugging insanity

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

VS Code Version: 1.47.3 running on OSX Catalina 10.15.3

I've been debugging the current extension project for the past few days without any issues.

Then suddenly, insanity enters my life.

The debugger is still running. Breakpoints have all turned to hollow circles and say they are unbound.  The code still stop on these breakpoints, but the line is no longer highlighted, just has a greyish outline, and the variables now show their definition, not their values.

I feel like I have hit a keyboard shortcut and switched to some obscure, unhelpful debug mode, but I cannot find a setting or shortcut that describes doing such a thing.

What did I do, how do I get back to normal debugging? Can anyone help?

Here's screenshot, the debugger is running, the grey outline box is usually filled yellow, or green, the breakpoint is usually a filled circle, and mouse over usually shows the value on the variable, not any more :-(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tried changing many settings, nothing worked.

Then deleted the node_module folder and ran npm install, et voila!

What changed in there I have no idea. Nothing was installed or removed for some time, but there you are, the mysteries of VS Code debugging.